# ExUnit - run all tests stored in a custom directory (not tests/)

Tags: unit-testing, elixir, elixir-mix

**I want to have two separate sets of unit tests in my Elixir project that I can run separately with different ExUnit configurations.** I am working on an ExUnit formatter and I am trying to write unit tests for it. In order to test it I figured I would create another directory (`example_tests`) containing a `test_helper.exs` file with similar to the one in `test/`, but with ExUnit configured to use my custom formatter. I added my formatter as an ExUnit formatter and then created a test module `example_tests`. The problem is now I don't know how to configure ExUnit to run all the tests in `example_tests/` with the configuration specified in `example_tests/test_helper.exs`.

I found there is a `test_paths` configuration parameter than can be set in the `mix.exs` file. The problem is that value is set on a per project basis and I need it to have two different values (normally just `["test"]` but then for the test run with the formatter `["example_tests"]`). I assumed I could override the configuration values on a per-task basis so I created an example_tests task as well, but I can't figure out how to alter the configuration.

**Is there a way to customize the project configuration (`Mix.Project.config`), on a per-task basis?** Or, is there better way to create two separate sets of tests with different ExUnit configurations?

**Update:**

Here is a link to the source code for the `test` Mix task: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/mix/lib/mix/tasks/test.ex

Answer (score 3):

You can put more than one path in `test_paths`, as long as they both have a test_helper.exs file, when the tests in a given path are executed, they are executed using the test helper for that path. So anything under `test` you could use the default formatter, but then anything under `example_test` could run with your custom formatter.

You could also run `ExUnit.configure(formatters: [MyFormatter])` in the `setup_all` callback for a given test module, so that all tests in that module use your formatter, and use the `on_exit` callback to switch it back to the default. You may need to set `async: false` though for your tests, since I think the formatter configuration is global for all tests - either that or use the moduletag attribute (for example `@moduletag :custom_formatter`) to mark which group a set of tests should be run as, and then use `mix test --include custom_formatter` and `mix test --exclude custom_formatter` to only run those tests together as a group. Then use mix task aliases to simplify your life (e.g. `mix test` runs tests with the default formatter and `mix test.custom` runs tests with your custom formatter.

Hopefully one of those is a workable solution for you!